# android animation: rabbit jumping and bouncing

Tags: android, animation, bounce

I am learning on some android animation, and would like to perform the following:

### Background:

A rabbit is originally sleeping on the grass. When pressing the button, it will jump high once vertically with reducing speed to midair (position X), and then start drop off from position X and bounce vertically for several time, and finally back to the original place.

During the flight, it will open its eye (drawable r_rabbit_wake400), 
while begin and after animation staying on the grass, it will close its eye (drawable r_rabbit_sleep400).

### Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{  
    ....        
    button_rabbit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.r_rabbit_sleep400);
    ....



public void button_action_click (View view) 
{
    button_rabbit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.r_rabbit_wake400);
    ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button_rabbit, "translationY", -500f, 0f);
    animY.setDuration(1500);//1.5sec
    animY.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
    animY.setRepeatCount(0);
    animY.start();  
}
```

### Question:

This will only give out a result that the rabbit immediately goes from grass with its eyes opened and directly to the air (without transition of decelerating speed), and then fall towards ground with bouncing off for several time back to the grass, and afterwards without its eye closed.

Should I separate the animation into 2 stages using those `AnimationListener`:

1. From grass to midair with decelerating speed (to position X)
2. From position X, start off bounce

?

If yes, how could that be written using those `onAnimationEnd`?
Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: *Should I separate the animation into 2 stages using those AnimationListener* - yes, but use an `AnimatorSet`. If I'm not mistaken there's an animation video example about what you want(with a ball however) in the DevBytes series on Youtube.

Comment: Thanks! I will do some more research!